# Supply Username and Password to witadmin

Tags: windows, tfs

Using `witadmin` I'm trying to delete a work item on a TFS in a *different domain*. I therefore use a login that is different from my Windows login, for which I'm asked when opening the web interface.

However, `witadmin` fails with the following message, not prompting for username and password:

> Unable to destroy work item(s) 1. TF237090: Does not exist or access
>   is denied.

Is there a way to supply credentials as arguments or explicitly make `witadmin` prompt for credentials?

Answer (score 3):

What solved my problem is the *Credential Manager*, which is in *Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Your Credentials*. I added an item to *Windows Credentials* containing containing the username and password I need for the TFS.

It doesn't make `witadmin` ask, but it takes these credentials.